# STM32 dma and dmamux what is benefit of dmamux

Tags: stm32, dma

Can anyone explain the benefit using dmamux feature and how it improve parallel peripheral performance between STM32L4 with and without dmamux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explain the benefit using dmamux feature

`dmamux` provides flexibility in connecting peripherals with DMA controller. Older versions of STM32 had it fixed.

> how it improve parallel peripheral performance between STM32L4 with
> and without dmamux?

I was not designed to improve the performance, but to provide more flexibility. But if you have periherals heavily using DMA you can connect to them to different ones reducing the probability of conflicts.

In some STM32 uCs you can chain DMA requests as well.

Comment: "But if you have peripherals heavily using DMA you can connect to them to different ones reducing the probability of conflicts." Thank for the reply, was it possible to expand with example how DAMMUX resolves conflicts based on that statement.

Comment: Same as sharing one peripheral for two tasks. If you use two peripherals the potential conflicts are minimized